# Javascript JSON field has \" after each pushed JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable with the following string value:

```
{"title":"Zebra Long Maxi Dress","subtitle":"Unique and comfortable Maxi dress that is easy to wear and fun to be seen in.","quantity":1,"price":150,"currency":"RON","image_url":"https://dl.airtable.com/1gGAho3dQ8uQfWpa5pEV_anne-1-(8).png"},{"title":"Blue fan dress","subtitle":"This blue fan dress will blow people away. With its custom cut design you will always stand out.\n","quantity":1,"price":100,"currency":"RON","image_url":"https://dl.airtable.com/oerRxGtZRuqnI9afPmn0_anne-1-(35).png"}
```

I am pushing this to the elements part of the below structure like this :

```
var messageData = { 
                    recipient : {
                        id: sender   
                    },
                    message:{
                        attachment:{
                            type:"template",
                            payload:{
                                template_type:"receipt",
                                recipient_name: clientName,
                                order_number: orderNumber,
                                currency:"RON",
                                payment_method:"Rambus",        
                                //order_url:"http://www.facebook.com",
                                //timestamp:"1428444852", 
                                elements:[],
                                address:{
                                    street_1:address,
                                    city:"Bucharest",
                                    postal_code:"0",
                                    state:"_",
                                    country:"RO"
                                },
                                summary:{
                                    subtotal:0,
                                    shipping_cost:0,
                                    total_tax:0,
                                    total_cost:totalCost
                                },
                                adjustments:[]
                            } // payload
                        } // attachment
                    } // message
                }; // messageData 

messageData.message.attachment.payload.elements.push(JSON.parse(elementArrayItemJson));
```

and I am getting the following output for the messageData variable, as you can see there is `\"` where there should only be `"` and also `"elements":["{\"title\":\"Zebra Long Maxi Dress\"` has an extra `"`

I'm not sure what to do to get the JSON to look correct.

```
{"recipient":{"id":"1588309797861804"},"message":{"attachment":{"type":"template","payload":{"template_type":"receipt","recipient_name":"Ethan Richardson","order_number":"70128","currency":"RON","payment_method":"Rambus","elements":["{\"title\":\"Zebra Long Maxi Dress\",\"subtitle\":\"Unique and comfortable Maxi dress that is easy to wear and fun to be seen in.\",\"quantity\":1,\"price\":150,\"currency\":\"RON\",\"image_url\":\"https://dl.airtable.com/1gGAho3dQ8uQfWpa5pEV_anne-1-(8).png\"}","{\"title\":\"Blue fan dress\",\"subtitle\":\"This blue fan dress will blow people away. With its custom cut design you will always stand out.\\n\",\"quantity\":1,\"price\":100,\"currency\":\"RON\",\"image_url\":\"https://dl.airtable.com/oerRxGtZRuqnI9afPmn0_anne-1-(35).png\"}"],"address":{"street_1":"Flat 35 Rossetti Court Byron Road","city":"Bucharest","postal_code":"0","state":"_","country":"RO"},"summary":{"subtotal":0,"shipping_cost":0,"total_tax":0,"total_cost":250},"adjustments":[]}}}}
```

Comment: If that's actually the contents of your string variable, then it should work. Are you sure that you're using `JSON.parse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your original variable is a string and not an object, it is being inserted into the new object as a string. The \" issue is just escaping the quotes so as not to close the string prematurely.

Convert your string into a JSON object to add it to the new object:

```
JSON.parse(json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `elementArrayItemJson` is an invalid JSON object. It has 2 root elements so JSON.parse is going to get caught in a Syntax Error due to the `,`.

The current string shows as follow after stringify:

```
{
    "title": "Zebra Long Maxi Dress",
    "subtitle": "Unique and comfortable Maxi dress that is easy to wear and fun to be seen in.",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 150,
    "currency": "RON",
    "image_url": "https://dl.airtable.com/1gGAho3dQ8uQfWpa5pEV_anne-1-(8).png"
}, {
    "title": "Blue fan dress",
    "subtitle": "This blue fan dress will blow people away. With its custom cut design you will always stand out.\n",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 100,
    "currency": "RON",
    "image_url": "https://dl.airtable.com/oerRxGtZRuqnI9afPmn0_anne-1-(35).png"
}
```

The `},{` shows that it contains 2 unnamed elements in your string.
So some options that you can do is to split the string by doing so:

```
elementArrayItemJson.replace('},{', '}\n{');
```

Then split by new line (\n) to get an array of valid JSON strings:

```
newElementArrayItemJson.split('\n');
```

Then you can push each of the elements using `JSON.parse(newElementArrayItemJson[0])`

This solution can be simplified quite a bit but it will show the error.

EDIT: Assuming your variable `elementArrayItemJson` is surrounded by single quotes since it is a string